# Is it safe to delete old bitlocker keys from AD

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, bitlocker

So I have a bunch of old bitlocker keys stored with some computer accounts (the msFVE-RecoveryInformation attribute):

[image]

Bitlocker has re-run multiple times and every time it re-encrypts it generates and backs up a new recovery password of course- so the "old" keys are no longer in use.

Is it safe to delete them or will that screw up something with the computer account?

Comment: By "old", you mean two days old?

Comment: Ha sorry I'll change the wording. I mean expired, encryption has re-run on the box and it generated a new recovery password

Comment: Recovery Information for each encrypted volume on the computer is stored separately so make sure you're not deleting the Recovery Information for a different volume.

Comment: Thats a good point I hadn't considered that. But this is only the OS volume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're certain you do not need the recovery keys (e.g. You re-imaged or otherwise re-keyed) then you may safely delete them from the computer object.